# Where can I get fresh new Wine DLLs?

Tags: wine

I was acting careless today and I accidentally deleted one of the `.dll`s in my Ubuntu Wine installation,  `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/ole32.dll` to be exact, and need a new fresh copy of only this one `.dll`.

I know that reinstalling will fix it, but I have installed quite a few programs and do not want to have to do such a drastic thing just to fix this one problem.

So, I'm wondering if there is somewhere that I can download this original `.dll` as it came with my original Wine installation.  I have found the SourceForge repository, but it only has `.h` and `.c` files and I do not know how to build them into a `.dll`.

Can anyone give me a link to download, or instructions to build my missing `.dll`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Aha!  Problem solved.**

I did a search on my computer for `ole32.dll` and found a file by the name of `ole32.dll.so` in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/`.  I noticed that it had about the same filesize that I remembered the old `ole32.dll` having.  Sounds kinda like the backup system that Windows uses...

So, I decided to copy it into the `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/` and rename it from `ole32.dll.so` to `ole32.dll`.  And then to try it out.  I ran `$ wineboot` to test it out, I held my breath the whole minute that it took to load.

And it worked!  *So, to summarize:*

I found a backup version in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/ole32.dll.so` and copied it into `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/` renaming it to `ole32.dll`, removing the `.so` extension.

Thanks to all that helped, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

I think this DLL came from Wine, so you could make a new Wine prefix:

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-bak winecfg
```

And then copy the DLL from `~/.wine-bak/drive_c/windows/system32/ole32.dll`.

I tried a locate and came up with this:

```
mohanan@mohanan-laptop:~$ locate ole32.dll
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/ole32.dll.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/fakedlls/ole32.dll
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine/ole32.dll.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine/fakedlls/ole32.dll
```

You could copy one of these, but I am not sure which one you'll need, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install wine by using -f:

```
sudo apt-get install -f wine
```

If that doesn't work then you might be forced to uninstall then re-install wine.

Answer (score 0):

sudo aptitude install wine-tricks . It can handle wine bottles for you ( make another bottle, in your home, copy the dll from it).
It can do other neath stuff like connect to microsoft/dowlooad.com/give instructions on how to get most of the default windows 7 and improve your bottle ( including directx, DCOM, iexplorer(lol), GDI+) Some of them are really worth it, especially GDI+ which makes some games work.
You are right on your answer, probably the dlls by default are symlinks for a template in the system.